# 100% width background image with an 'auto' height

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive, responsive-images

I'm currently working on a mobile landing page for a company. It's a really basic layout but below the header there's an image of a product which will always be 100% width (the design shows it always going from edge to edge). Depending on the width of the screen the height of the image will obviously adjust accordingly. I originally did this with an img (with a CSS width of 100%) and it worked great but I've realised that I'd like to use media queries to serve different images based on different resolutions - let's say a small, medium and a large version of the same image, for example. I know you can't change the img src with CSS so I figured I should be using a CSS background for the image as opposed to an img tag in the HTML.

I can't seem to get this working properly as the div with the background image needs both a width and a height to show the background. I can obviously use 'width: 100%' but what do I use for the height? I can put a random fixed height like 150px and then I can see the top 150px of the image but this isn't the solution as there isn't a fixed height. I had a play and found that once there is a height (tested with 150px) I can use 'background-size: 100%' to fit the image in the div correctly. I can use the more recent CSS3 for this project as it's aimed solely at mobile.

I've added a rough example below. Please excuse the inline styles but I wanted to give a basic example to try and make my question a little clearer.

```
<div id="image-container">
    <div id="image" style="background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat; width: 100%; height: 150px; background-size: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Do I maybe have to give the container div a percentage height based on the whole page or am I looking at this completely wrong?

Also, do you think CSS backgrounds are the best way to do this? Maybe there's a technique which serves different img tags based on device/screen width. The general idea is that the landing page template will be used numerous times with different product images so I need to make sure I develop this the best way possible.

I apologise is this is a little long-winded but I'm back and forth from this project to the next so I'd like to get this little thing done.

Comment: A browser may opt not to download an image resource if it has display: none, so you can always show different images with media queries without JS

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of using `background-image` you can use `img` directly and to get the image to spread all the width of the viewport try using `max-width:100%;`.

Please remember; don't apply any padding or margin to your main container div as they will increase the total width of the container. Using this rule, you can have a image width equal to the width of the browser and the height will also change according to the aspect ratio.

Edit: Changing the image on different size of the window

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var imgSrc = $('#image');
  if(windowWidth <= 400){           
    imgSrc.attr('src','http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a');
  }
  else if(windowWidth > 400){
    imgSrc.attr('src','https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-container">
  <img id="image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" alt=""/>
</div>
```

In this way you change your image in different size of the browser.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this for me, it's much appreciated. I just gave it a quick go and it seems to be working.

Comment: This old answer looked attractive ... but isn't it true that the mobile browser will still download (just not display) the image initially set in the HTML as src? If so, that's a non-starter, since the point is to conserve the mobile device's resources.

Comment: I believe Tim Gallant is right on this one - in this case the browser will load both images as a resource and then just display the lower resolution one. So while this seems attractive, on mobile it's actually slower than loading only the high res one and with that sacrifice you'll only see the lower resolution image... worst of both worlds.

Comment: Poor answer. Downvoted. Simply bloated and old code.

Comment: Insert media queries that add display: none to the images you don't want to show - most browsers won't download them

Answer (score 235):

Tim S. was much closer to a "correct" answer then the currently accepted one. If you want to have a 100% width, variable height background image done with CSS, instead of using `cover` (which will allow the image to extend out from the sides) or `contain` (which does not allow the image to extend out at all), just set the CSS like so:

```
body {
    background-image: url(img.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

This will set your background image to 100% width and allow the height to overflow. Now you can use media queries to swap out that image instead of relying on JavaScript.

EDIT: I just realized (3 months later) that you probably don't want the image to overflow; you seem to want the container element to resize based on it's background-image (to preserve it's aspect ratio), which is not possible with CSS as far as I know.

Hopefully soon you'll be able to use the new [srcset](http://drafts.htmlwg.org/srcset/w3c-srcset/#additions-to-the-img-element) attribute on the `img` element. If you want to use `img` elements now, the currently accepted answer is probably best.

However, you can create a responsive background-image element with a constant aspect ratio using purely CSS. To do this, you set the `height` to 0 and set the `padding-bottom` to a percentage of the element's own width, like so:

```
.foo {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0; /* remove any pre-existing padding, just in case */
    padding-bottom: 75%; /* for a 4:3 aspect ratio */
    background-image: url(foo.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In order to use different aspect ratios, divide the height of the original image by it's own width, and multiply by 100 to get the percentage value. This works because padding percentage is always calculated based on width, even if it's vertical padding.

Comment: Answers like this should be the accepted ones, they answer the question. Sure give a "best solution" but also answer the question then when people find it they will get the answer they want!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I am using Google Chrome 47.0. Can it be because the answer is outdated?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what part is not working? I gave several possible answers, so if one part isn't working I can elaborate further to give a better and more up-to-date answer.

Comment: for some unclear reason, setting `background-size: auto` solved my issue on all devices orientations.

Answer (score 22):

**Try this**

```
html { 
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

**Simplified version**

```
html {
  background: url(image.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the CSS property `background-size` and set it to `cover` or `contain`, depending your preference. Cover will cover the window entirely, while contain will make one side fit the window thus not covering the entire page (unless the aspect ratio of the screen is equal to the image).

Please note that this is a CSS3 property. In older browsers, this property is ignored. Alternatively, you can use javascript to change the CSS settings depending on the window size, but this isn't preferred.

```
body {
    background-image: url(image.jpg); /* image */
    background-position: center;      /* center the image */
    background-size: cover;           /* cover the entire window */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use a two color background image:

```
<div style="width:100%; background:url('images/bkgmid.png');
       background-size: cover;">
content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the css:

```
   html,body{
        height:100%;
        }
    .bg-img {
        background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center top; 
        background-size: cover; 
        height:100%;     
    }
```

And html is:

```
<div class="bg-mg"></div>
```

[CSS: stretching background image to 100% width and height of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887548/css-stretching-background-image-to-100-width-and-height-of-screen)

Answer (score 2):

It's 2017, and now you can use [object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) which has [decent support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit). It works in the same way as a div's `background-size` but on the element itself, and on any element including images.

```
.your-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html{
    height:100%;
    }
.bg-img {
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center top; 
    background-size: cover; 
    height:100vh;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing your problem. Two solutions come to my mind through HTML and CSS :

**Solution 1) HTML img tag**

```css
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ht1YnwcD/example.png">
</div>
```

**Solution 2) CSS background image**

First find width and height of your image file, you can right click on your image and choose **Properties** then go to **details** tab. you can see your image dimensions (according to the picture).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGPt3.jpg)

Then remember them.

```css
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    // height: calc(100vw / (your image width / image height));
    height: calc(100vw / (812 / 133));
    background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/ht1YnwcD/example.png');
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"></div>
```

I hope it was useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#car-container { 
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
} 
#car-image {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
} 
#abaya {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 z-index: 1;
} 
#girl {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-image: url('https://path-to-your-girl-image.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 z-index: 2;
}
```