# How to display full page background image on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have done some googling and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548338/full-screen-responsive-background-image)-ing; wound up on this [Perfect Full Page Background Image article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). I also tried using the image on jumbotron as said [here](http://www.boldoutlook.com/bootstrap-jumbotron-background-cover-image/), but everything I did gave me the same result. I figured it's not the instruction's fault, but something in my code is *hindering* the full image. The app is done on Rails. I am using `bootstrap-sass` gem.

This is what it currently looks like *(it looks exactly like this no matter what I do below)*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RK9j.jpg

If you notice, there is a small white gap between header and the top of the image, and there is a large gap between the bottom of the image to the horizontal line of footer. I want to make the image to cover the whole page (100% cover), something like [this](http://ringvemedia.com/) or [this one](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php).

This is what layouts/application.html.erb look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My site</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
  <p class="notice"><%= notice%></p>
  <p class="alert"><%=alert%></p>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

I  have tried each (separately):

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 url(../assets/my_image.jpg) center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
<img src="my_image/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">

#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I have also tried deleting **everything else** on `application.scss` (save the `jumbotron` code above), but it *still* looks like the screenshot image.

Footer:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      (some text)    
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Header:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       (some text)
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Why does my image not cover 100% screen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887548/css-stretching-background-image-to-100-width-and-height-of-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could add in body some css (unrelated to bootstrap) i.g:

```
body {
  background-image: url('../path');
  background-position: cover;}
```

As such:

https://jsfiddle.net/jxw31qtd/

or repeat a smaller background throughout the screen with (repeat-x and repeat-y) as such:

https://jsfiddle.net/24219gj5/

Answer (score 2):

---

If images are in assets/img no need to give any path(eg.absolute,relative)

### You can try this as well

```
body {
background-image:url("myImage.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```