# How to set a full background image in CSS using reactjs style?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image

Here I have one div This div image I want to set on whole background but it not set full background(see below screenshot). My project is using reactjs. How to set Image in whole background ?

[image]

```
<div
   style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${defaultImages.backgroundOfImage})`,
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition: 'cover',
   }}
  >
</div>
```

Comment: `backgroundSize`, not `backgroundPosition`. This is mainly about not knowing which CSS rule to use, has nothing to do with React.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887548/css-stretching-background-image-to-100-width-and-height-of-screen. Not closing as this is on CSS and this post is on react

Comment: you can have a look over here a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/39196525/8425297

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I use backgroundSize so My image goes blur how to stop to blur background image

Comment: @DDD, is it blur because your image is too small to take the cover size or do you have a blur effect in your image (photoshop or CSS property) ?

Comment: @KévinHuang css property

Comment: @DDD, `filter: blur(0);` to disallow blur CSS effect

Answer (score 3):

The CSS property you are looking for is `background-size`, not `background-position`. The snippet that I normally use for doing this is:

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-image: url(path/to/image);
```

Or with React

```
<div style={{
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
  backgroundImage: `url(${pathToImage})`,
}} />
```

**Edit:** This is probably out of the scope of the question, but I suggest you declare the style object somewhere else and import it each time you want to have the same background effect for reusability's sake

Comment: I refer your answer It works but My image goes blur how to stop to blur image

Comment: @DDD That's because your image is to small. Perhaps you need to get a larger one

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ReactJS, but merely CSS issue.
You should use `background-size:cover` instead of `background-position` since background position property sets the starting position of a background image, but not setting the size of image.