# How do I mitigate the 'zoomed in effect' of a hero image that covers 100%width of the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm creating a hero image section on my hobby site, which stretches 100%width of the viewport. Every image I upload has this zoomed in effect.Like you dont'see the whole picture just a portion of it.

I know I can use background-repeat, size and cover to play around with how I want the image to be presented. But is there a way for me to display the image without the browser cropping off a good portion of the image?

It seems like even when I resize the images it doesn't work either because the width is always 100% of the viewport.

Just curious if anyone has found a solution to countering the 'zoomed in' effect of an image taking 100% width of the viewport.

Comment: Code please , a working example will be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the cover background property, at least try and set the height to 100%, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22887578/6309), and [its fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XUjP/).

```
body {
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/aZO5Kolb.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html {
    height: 100%
}
```

That should stretch the all image within your viewport.

Comment: VonC you da man sir. I had been using background-size all wrong. Was using it to position the image in the container or to cover it. This is great because I change image size depending on viewport to make a resolution work. thanks a lot!

Comment: @noobcoderiam You are welcome: you can edit this answer to illustrate how you associate the size and viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the height or aspect ratio of a user's viewport compared to the image size/ratio, so there will always be a possibility of cropping off from the width or the height when using `background-size: cover`.

In order to keep your aspect ratio for the image and cover the element with it, you can use `background-position` to the "focal point" of the image. For instance if the main part of the picture is at near the bottom right of the image, then you can set the `background-position: 90% 90%`. That way it the covering has to crop, it'll at least try to move the image so that the main subject is centered always in frame.

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/700) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

Comment: this is waht I was doing previously with background position. it works well. I think my solution might end up being a photoshop one, where I learn to center images better or resize them

Comment: @noobcoderiam, if you already have photoshop, that can at least help you determine the exact % or px from the top left that you want to center. You can just put that into your `background-position` property.

Comment: another excellent point. I actually just did that. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it a lot dude.