# Android soft keyboard resizes background image (website)

Tags: android, css

I have a similar problem to this: [Software keyboard resizes background image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/software-keyboard-resizes-background-image-on-android)

The solutions given there are for Android development. They don't help. I'm seeking a solution for websites in general using CSS/JavaScript.

My current CSS:

```
#video_mob {
position: fixed;
background: url(../terminal/background.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -1000;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

One option sort of fixes it, but the background actually shifts itself upwards.

```
-webkit-background-size: 280% auto;
```

Any further ideas? CSS or JS solutions welcome.

Comment: yeah... this question might be helpful for you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099930/100-width-background-image-with-an-auto-height

Comment: Here's an idea, try `background-attachment: fixed` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` didn't work, but thanks sweeds for investigating :) I found a solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, solution found! Silly me.

FYI this is the requirement:

```
background: url(../terminal/background.gif) no-repeat center top fixed;
background-size: 280% auto;
```

Had to set the position to center top.

Comment: Mark your solution as the answer if this solved your issue... which it seems like it did.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to do that, lol

Comment: 2 days over now :)