# How to make header's height depend on background image height?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, underscores-wp

Trying to find the answer quite long, but I am not even sure how to express the question to searchbar - so I'll try to explain here and if you know that it was already answered I will be happy for the link :)

I am creating a wordpress theme using The Underscores framework. I want make my header to be dependent on the background image height. I mean - I can upload there an image of any size and header's width will be 100 % of image and height wll be dynamically change according the screen size.

Better for imagination, here's an example:
http://hitchdiary.cz/

Try to change size of the window - image is allways fully displayed and the height of the header changes.

So that's what I want. What I have is a static size header and background image is adjusting according the screen size.

```
.site-header {            
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Header image is set by user in wordpress adjust section. In code it is this way:

```
<?php if ( get_header_image() ){ ?>
            <header id="masthead" class="site-header" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>)" role="banner">
    <?php } else { ?>
            <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks for any advice. Sorry if that's obvious. I'm quite a newbie.

WHAT'S GOING NOW:

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi3hf.jpg)

Comment: any demo about whats currently happening

Answer (score 1):

The height is calculated automatically according to the content in the div. By setting it to 100% you're telling it to take the height of the parent container.

Setting height to auto will solve your problem.

```
.site-header {            
    width: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: 100%;
}

or 

.site-header {            
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

*Flexible Width*

**Sorry I mistook it to be flexible width instead of height. Please ignore what comes below this statment. However it might help you in adjusting width in the future.**

By default div, header, footer etc are block elements. They take up 100% of the parent div.

Say you have a

```
<div class="parent" style="width:500px;">
    <div class="child"> </div>       
</div>
```

Here the inner div takes up 500px as well.

I tried out similar code, all you have to do set display to inline.

```
.site-header {
    display: inline;
}
```

You can even try floating it to the left/right in case making it inline doesn't work.

You can read more about the differences between [block and inline](https://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reaction! However ii doesn't work for me. I guess there will be some magic in code I can't see or I just did something wrong :/

Comment: Please share some more details then. I'll try fixing it. This is what is done for height. It automatically takes up the height of the content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099930/100-width-background-image-with-an-auto-height?rq=1

Read this. It suggests using an image tag directly. Why do you want to use the image as the background? Using the <img> tag inside works as well.

Comment: Thanks! I just followed tutorial - that's why ;) I used img tag and the Image behaves the way I want now. But I am solving another problem - how to make content (site name and site description) overlay the header.

Comment: @Balu Use position absolute and Z Index. You can google those. Quite easy :)
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/